# DESDM COADD image access

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

I'm just starting a project to analyze some of the images obtained from the Dark Energy Survey (DES), and I'd like to get some of the COADD images from the SV data.

For example, this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03062v1.pdf shows a series of images that are apparently from the 'DESDM database of coadd objects'.  Just looking at image (a) on page 3 of the paper, I can find images in the DES Y1 data from NOAO Science Archive at http://archive.noao.edu/ that show the objects in image (a) from the paper, but they are individual exposures - I can't find any COADDed images.

Can anyone tell me how to get these COADD images?